# Django url not finding a template using CreateView in Class-Based Views

Tags: python, django

I have created a page where a user can add a new item (notes in this case) and I am making use of CBV which I have recently started learning.

This is my model form

```
class NoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Note
    fields = ('title', 'note', 'tags')
```

This is the view in views.py

```
class NoteCreate(CreateView):
    model = Note
    form_class = NoteForm
    template_name = "add_note.html"
```

Then this is the url as I used in the urls.py of the app

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from . import views
from madNotes.views import  NoteCreate, NoteIndex, 

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^notes/add/$', NoteCreate.as_view(), name="new_note"),
    url(r'^$', NoteIndex.as_view()),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>\S+)/$', views.NoteDetail.as_view(), name="entry_detail"),

 )
```

NB: I used the same url as the main page at 127.0.0.1:8000 in the projects urls.py file and it worked.

I have seen several tutorials and even the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/) and can't seem to find what I am doing wrong. Will I also need to add a function in order for it to be saved in the db or the CBV will do it all?

EDit: The error I get is this

> Page not found (404)
>   Request Method:     GET
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/notes/add/

Here is the project's urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from MadNotez import settings
from registration.backends.default.views import RegistrationView
from madNotes.forms import ExRegistrationForm
if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    url(r'accounts/register/$', RegistrationView.as_view(form_class = ExRegistrationForm), name='registration_register'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url('^markdown/', include('django_markdown.urls')),
    url('^notes/', include('madNotes.urls')),
    #url(r'^$', views.NoteCreate.as_view(), name="new note"), when I used it here it worked
)
```

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: What is the error you get? Have you tried to remove the space in the url's name -> 'new_note' ?

Comment: @Gocht I just did, same error. I actually got the page when I set it as the default page of the app from the project's urls.py file, I wonder why it's not working in the apps urls.py

Comment: @Gocht that was my first thought too, but I just tried a url name with spaces in my own project and it worked strangely enough. It seems Django isn't that strict about url names.

Comment: Do you have more urls defined in the same file than this one? Are they working properly?

Comment: @petroleyum I have never tried that, that why I suggested. It's good to know.

Comment: yea, they are all working properly.  @petroleyum I also used it with the spaces in the projects urls.py file and it worked, now I brought the same thing to the apps urls.py and strangely enough not working

Comment: Please, provide the full urls.py file

Comment: I just added the full urls.py file

Comment: you say that is the `urls.py` of the `app`. Please show the `urls.py` of the main project (i.e. the one that includes the one you show now). Presumably, there is a prefix to be inserted in the URI... e.g. `url(r'^app_prefix/', include('appname.urls',...`, so your URI should be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_prefix/notes/add/`

Comment: see? You are missing a `notes`

Comment: [http://127.0.0.1:8000/notes/notes/add/] you mean like this?

Comment: yes, see my [updated] answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you say that is the `urls.py` of the `app`, which means it is included by the project's `urls.py`.

As you show now, all the app's URIs go under the `notes` prefix:

```
url('^notes/', include('madNotes.urls')),
```

so as things stand at present the correct URI for the page is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/notes/notes/add/
```

In order to clean things up a bit, I'd suggest to modify the app's `urls.py` to

```
url(r'^add/$', NoteCreate.as_view(), name="new_note"),
```

so that the page can be reached at

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/notes/add/
```

This way all the app's pages/services are available under the `notes` prefix and with a simple name that is consistent with their action (i.e. `add`, `delete`, etc)

Comment: wow...worked!!! thanks. I would love to clean it and make it /notes/add instead. What do I remove to make it that way?

Comment: Glad to help. See the answer :)